# cannot evaluate expression because a native frame is on top of the call stack and system.accessviolationexception

Tags: c#, opencv

I have this code using c#.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{

    private CvCapture VideoCapture;

    private IplImage frame;
    private IplImage imgMain;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    private void btnVideo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double vidWidth, vidHeight;

        try
        {
            VideoCapture = highgui.CvCreateCameraCapture(0);
        }
        catch (Exception except)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(except.Message);
        }

        if (btnVideo.Text.CompareTo("Start Video") == 0)
        {

            if (VideoCapture.ptr == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("badtrip ah!!!");
                return;
            }

            btnVideo.Text = "Stop Video";

            highgui.CvSetCaptureProperty(ref VideoCapture, highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
            highgui.CvSetCaptureProperty(ref VideoCapture, highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);

            highgui.CvQueryFrame(ref VideoCapture);

            vidWidth = highgui.cvGetCaptureProperty(VideoCapture, highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
            vidHeight = highgui.cvGetCaptureProperty(VideoCapture, highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);

            picBoxMain.Width = (int)vidWidth;
            picBoxMain.Height = (int)vidHeight;


            timerGrab.Enabled = true;
            timerGrab.Interval = 42;
            timerGrab.Start();

        }

        else
        {
            btnVideo.Text = "Start Video";
            timerGrab.Enabled = false;

            if (VideoCapture.ptr == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                highgui.CvReleaseCapture(ref VideoCapture);
                VideoCapture.ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
        }
    }

    private void timerGrab_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            frame = highgui.CvQueryFrame(ref VideoCapture);

            if (frame.ptr == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                timerGrab.Stop();
                MessageBox.Show("??");
                return;
            }

            imgMain = cxcore.CvCreateImage(cxcore.CvGetSize(ref frame), 8, 3);

            picBoxMain.Image = highgui.ToBitmap(imgMain, false);

            cxcore.CvReleaseImage(ref imgMain);
            //cxcore.CvReleaseImage(ref frame);
        }
        catch (Exception excpt)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(excpt.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is after i break all and step through the debugger the program stops at a certain code.

the code where it stops is here: frame = highgui.CvQueryFrame(ref VideoCapture);
the error is that it says that cannot evaluate expression because a native frame is on top of the call stack.

and then when i try to shift+F11 it. there is another error saying that system.accessviolationexception.

the stack trace says that:    at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.CopyToManaged(IntPtr source, Object destination, Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
   at CxCore.IplImage.get_ImageDataDb()

> Here is the error i get when i changed the c# opencv wrapper i used
>   from the cvlib to cvwrapcs230d.
>
> Also the DLL's used in the project is included in the folder.
>
> But when i changed the wrapper from cvwrapcs230d to cvwrap230 here is
>   the error i get.
>
> The first Note is the cvwrapcs230d wrapper used while the second is
>   the cvwrapcs230 wrapper.
>
> 1st Note: cvwrapcs230d
>   -Thrown: "Unable to load DLL 'cvwrapcpp230': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"
>   (System.DllNotFoundException) Exception Message = "Unable to load DLL
>   'cvwrapcpp230': The specified module could not be found. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)", Exception Type =
>   "System.DllNotFoundException"  Exception Message  "Unable to load DLL
>   'cvwrapcpp230': The specified module could not be found. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"    string Exception
>   Type  "System.DllNotFoundException"   string
>   -Thrown: "The type initializer for 'cvlib' threw an exception." (System.TypeInitializationException)  Exception Message = "The type
>   initializer for 'cvlib' threw an exception.", Exception Type =
>   "System.TypeInitializationException"   Exception Message  "The type
>   initializer for 'cvlib' threw an exception."  string Exception
>   Type  "System.TypeInitializationException"    string Stopped at
>   Exception
>
> 2nd Note: cvwrapcs230
>   -Thrown: "Unable to load DLL 'cvwrapcpp230': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"
>   (System.DllNotFoundException) Exception Message = "Unable to load DLL
>   'cvwrapcpp230': The specified module could not be found. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)", Exception Type =
>   "System.DllNotFoundException"  Exception Message  "Unable to load DLL
>   'cvwrapcpp230': The specified module could not be found. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"    string Exception
>   Type  "System.DllNotFoundException"   string
>   -cvCreateCameraCapture    cvlib.cvCreateCameraCapture(index = {unknown})   index  {unknown}   int

Comment: What library is CvQueryFrame in? The error message you are getting indicates the error is in the dll (or more likely, how you are calling the dll). Marshalling is the process by which objects move in and out of the managed c# landscape into unsafe non-c# code.

Comment: That `timerGrab.Interval = 42;` is really tiny, what Timer are you using? you could be running in to issues of multiple threads trying to access variables at the same time.

Comment: the timer i use is the timer in the visual studio. 
system.windows.forms.timer

Comment: @Mikeb the library of the cvqueryframe is in opencv C# wrapper cvlibcs. i changed it to cvwrapcs230d and still it is not good.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain the timer i use is the timer in the visual studio. system.windows.forms.timer

Comment: [There are 3 diffrent timers built in to .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx). `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` is what I wanted to know, that timer runs its Tick events on the UI thread so it is not a thread safty issue (unless you are using threads elsewhere). Please hit the "[copy exception detail to the clipboard](http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/saraford/WindowsLiveWriter/Didyouknowyoucancopytheexceptiondetailsw_F67C/image_2.png)" link on both exceptions you get and paste the full text [as a edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19863166/edit) to your original question.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I try to click the copy exception detail to the clipboard but nothing happens. because the exception i encounter is when i break all the program after debugging.

also i try to changed the interval to 5000 but also nothing happens.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain i post the edited question of mine and the errors i get.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I think the problem is in the cvqueryframe.